# Unable to read excel with leading zero in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

If I read excel it's read as

```
   SKU Code Location Code  GIT
    123456           100   10
    123456           200   20
    123456           300    0
```

but actually my excel data is

```
   SKU Code Location Code  GIT
    123456           0100   10
    123456           0200   20
    123456           0300    0
```

I have tried the below

```
gitDataDF = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx",
                           sheet_name='Sheet1', inferSchema='true'
                          ,converters={'Location Code': str})
```

and

```
gitDataDF = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx",
                           sheet_name='Sheet1', inferSchema='true'
                          ,dtype={'Location Code': np.str})
```

Update 1 :
The length of the value is not fixed. It might be 'N'

What should I do to read as it is. Can you help me to solve this?

For your information I am using, Python version - 3.8

Pandas version - 1.0.5

Comment: For me working well, one idea - are data in column like strings with zeros in excel?

Comment: No, it's on number data type @jezrael

Comment: So if there are numbers in excel, there are no zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an f-string:

```
gitDataDF = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx",
                           sheet_name='Sheet1', inferSchema='true'
                          ,converters={'Location Code': lambda x: f'{x:04}'})
```

Comment: @T.SURESH ARUNACHALAM Oh, I see. Have you tried using dtype instead of converters?